# "Zero" a mercurial repository

Tags: mercurial

I have mercurial repository with several thousand changesets.  Is there a way to say the state at a current changeset is the new "zero", baseline, initial commit?

```
Rev00000 ... Rev90000 ... 

would become:

RepoState@Rev90000 ...
```

Comment: `hg archive` + `hg init` + `hg add` + `hg commit -m "Initial commit"`?

Comment: @OmriBarel:  For that to work correctly, we'd have to make sure every link to that repo is dropped, right?

Comment: Yes, it's building an entirely new repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commenters have your answer and the short answer is "no".  You could easily build a new repository whose first commit is the most recent archive/snapshot from your old one, but it will be an entirely new repository and anyone pulling from it would get "is unrelated" and if they used "--force" they'd have all of the old one and all of the new one.  Similarly if they pushed to it with "--force" it would just fill up w/ the old stuff again.

So, unless you're willing to make everyone delete all their clones and reclone (essentially start over w/ a new snapshot) you're stuck.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `convert` extension to rewrite the history. To do it, let's assume local revision 950 is to be the new local revision zero in the new repository.

Enable the extension by adding the following to the `mercurial.ini` file:

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

Then run convert using revision 950 as the start of the conversion:

```
hg convert --config convert.hg.startrev=950 c:\repo c:\repo.new
```

All users would then have to clone the new repository `repo.new`.

Comment: How come it is necessary to use the splicemap first? If you ran the convert without that, what would be the difference?

Comment: @DaveInCaz It's not necessary.  I don't know what I was thinking.  Must have been using splicemap at the time.  Funny it took 3+ years for someone to notice.  I'll update the answer.